# Set custom title bar in PreferenceAcivity

Tags: android

I am using PreferenceActivity, how can I set a custom title bar? Not only text but background color, size - the whole layout.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`PreferenceActivity extends ListActivity`, and when you inflate the preferences from xml with `addPreferencesFromResource()`, it puts the stuff into the standard `ListView` that `ListActivity` uses.

So basically, you can use `setContentView()` to specify a layout, but you need to have a `ListView` in it with the id `"@+android:id/list"`.

So using kleini's example code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.login_settings);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_settings_layout);
}
```

You would need a ListView in `login_settings_layout.xml` that looks something like:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Comment: `@+android:id/list` should be `@android:id/list`

Answer (score 2):

This is the only thing that worked for me. Rest of the above stuff did not fetch desired results on my 4.3 Nexus Tablet.

I could not really recreate a proper actionbar like widget, but was able to put a large 'Settings' title on top of the PreferenceActivity, with below steps.

I got the hint from another stackoverflow answer and am just making it more elaborate.

1. In PreferenceActivity class (remove the existing titlebar)

   ```
   public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity· {
     ...
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // This goes first
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
   ```
2. In res/xml/settings.xml, I would like to draw attention to the first PreferenceCategory

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <PreferenceCategory
         android:layout="@layout/settings_titlebar" />

      <PreferenceCategory android:title="Notifications">
         <Preference .....
   ```
3. In res/layout/settings_titlebar.xml

Navals-MacBook-Pro:ver_ui_0.2 Naval$ vi res/layout/settings_titlebar.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="@drawable/header_background"
     android:enabled="false">

     <TextView android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ben's method worked out well for me!!. Here is the code

```
public class PreferenceCustomTitleActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

    /** Customize your background, textsize, cachetint, dividers
        for your list view in the xml **/
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_with_simple_listview_only);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    View preferenceHeader = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.preference_header, null);
    list.addHeaderView(preferenceHeader);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, worked fine for "NO_TITLE":

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.login_settings);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_settings_layout);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post login_settings_layout.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.customtitlebar); 
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

With a customtitlebar.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/customTitleBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/CustomWindowTitle">
</TextView>
```